# jQuery plugin doesn't load

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, drupal

I would like to use [this Facebook Wall plugin](https://github.com/thomasclausen/jquery-facebook-wall/blob/master/facebook_wall.plugin.js) on my website, but the problem is that it does not load. I've added a block in which i've put following html:

```
<div class="fb-plugin">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/drupal7/drupal-7.23/sites/all/themes/adaptivetheme/at_subtheme/js/facebook_wall.plugin.js"></script>
</div>
```

Moreover I've added this line to the theme.info file:

```
scripts[] = js/facebook_wall.plugin.js
```

But the plugin doesn't seem to work. Empty div appears. What is my mistake?

Comment: You might want to put quotes around that.

Comment: It's not the issue. .info file doesn't require quotes there.